# Bean property 'iUserGeneratorInterface' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: spring

**I have a project structure as follows**
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1jvh.png

**I have a class and interface defined in create-user**

**UserGeneratorInterface**

```
package com.credit.userGenerator;
public interface UserGeneratorInterface {
    public String userIdGenerator();
}
```

**RandomUserGenerator.java**

```
public class RandomUserGenerator implements UserGeneratorInterface {
    public static enum Mode {
        ALPHA, ALPHANUMERIC, NUMERIC 
    }
    public static String generateRandomString(int length, Mode mode) throws Exception {
                code logic
    }
    public String userIdGenerator(){
      code logic
    }
}
```

**I have defined application context in da-web and wan to get service of RandomUserGenerator.java**

```
public class ApplicationSignManager implements IApplicationSignInterface {
public UserGeneratorInterface iUserGeneratorInterface;
public UserGeneratorInterface getiUserGeneratorInterface() {
    return iUserGeneratorInterface;
}
public void setiUserGeneratorInterface(
        UserGeneratorInterface iUserGeneratorInterface) {
    this.iUserGeneratorInterface = iUserGeneratorInterface;
    }
}
```

**AppContext.xml**

```
<bean id="userGenerator" class="com.credit.userGenerator.RandomUserGenerator" ></bean>
<bean id="appSign" class="com.*****.service.ApplicationSignManager">
 <description>List of Dao in ApplicationLogin Manager</description>
 <property name="userGeneratorInterface" ref="userGenerator"/>
</bean>
```

**But I am getting the following exception**

*Bean property 'iUserGeneratorInterface' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?*

Comment: Indeed. If bean property (field) name is `iUserGeneratorInterface`, setter name should be `setIUserGeneratorInterface`. Notice the capital `I`. Also goes for getter. For clarity, better call it `userGeneratorInterface`.

Comment: The error still exist.Error creating bean with name 'appSign' defined in ServletContextresource[/WEBINF/applicationFlowContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'userGeneratorInterface' of bean class [com.bhaskar.service.ApplicationSignManager]: Bean property 'userGeneratorInterface' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: Excuse me for the simple question, but .. `com.*****.service.UserGenerator` implements `UserGeneratorInterface` ? because your ref used `com.*****.service.UserGenerator`

Comment: Thanks Xstian for pointing out the typo. I have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As noticed in the comments, use setIUserGeneratorInterface() and getIUserGeneratorInterface() with capital 'I'.
2. Use 'property name="iUserGeneratorInterface" ref="userGenerator"' - note the leading 'i'.

Note that it is always advisable to use well-established practices when naming your classes and fields. In your case naming 'UserGeneratorInterface' simply 'UserGenerator' and naming the field 'iUserGeneratorInterface' simply 'userGenerator' would make more sense. Note also that you have declared this field public (although this has nothing to do with the errors).

Answer (score 0):

Your bean id="userGenerator" 
Use this "userGenerator" like (public UserGeneratorInterface userGenerator;) as same as the variable name. 
And create getter, setter for this variable
then try